# docker compose building sequence

Tags: laravel, docker, docker-compose

I have a multi-container app (Laravel+Nginx+PostgreSQL) and I using docker compose to build my app.
I need to run `php artisan migrate` inside my Laravel container in the building process, but I have an issue - Laravel container can start building first before Postgres container, so I got the error because my DB host is not ready. 
How can I set something like "building sequence" in my `docker-compose.yml`?

My current `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3.3'
services:

  phpfpm:
    build:
      context: laravel-docker
    depends_on:
      - db
    container_name: phpfpm
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - /var/www/html/vendor/
      - ./laravel-docker:/var/www/html
    networks:
      - app-network

  db:
    image: postgres:9.6.5-alpine
    container_name: db
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: blabla
      POSTGRES_USER: blabla
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: blabla
    volumes:
      - ./db_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    networks:
      - app-network
```

and `laravel-docker/Dockerfile`:

```
FROM php:7.3.0-fpm-alpine3.8

//...

RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html
RUN chmod 755 -R /var/www/html && chmod -R o+w storage/

USER www-data

RUN composer install
RUN composer dump-autoload
COPY .env.example .env
// I need to migrate here when DB container will be ready
```

Comment: Hi, looking at your configuration, the 'db' service should start running first.... is this the case ?

Comment: All build steps can happen before any container is running, and won’t be connected to the Docker internal network that Docker Compose creates for you.  Among other things, you cannot run database migrations from a Dockerfile.

Comment: (Also remember that you can delete and recreate the database container, and then re-run an application container based on the same image; or export the built image to another system.)

Answer (score 0):

Dockerfile is not a good choice for database migration operations. The image should be able to build itself in isolation from other containers.

Database migration is more suited to be a boot-time operation, rather than a build-time operation. A good place for it would be image's entrypoint script, or as a separate "init" job when booting the docker stack - depending on what you feel more comfortable with.